# Получение ресурсов в Release

Tags: c#, resources, xamarin.forms

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу получить вложенный ресурс в Release. В Debug все работает. Код нашел на странице Microsoft(https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows). Никакой информации в интернете не нашел по этому задаю этот вопрос.

1. Почему я не могу получить добавленный мною ресурс именно в сборке Release?
2. Есть ли альтернативы?

Я пытался присвоить переменной b массив, но вот что говорит. 
[image: Первая попытка]

А это тот самый пример из Microsoft.
[image: Вторая попытка]

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде все нормально.

Отладчик не может вычислить b и files потому что в переменные живут от объявления до последнего использования. К тому же, он вполне может переставлять местами код и инлайнить все подряд. Переменной b как таковой может к этому моменту и не быть (или еще не быть)

В Debug JIT отключает оптимизацию, старается сохранить порядок выполнения и специально продлевает время жизни переменных до конца области видимости - жертвует производительностью ради  удобства отладки.

Comment: Возможно вы и правы. Но я ни как не могу понять почему в первый раз(фото 1) в режиме отладки я могу получить шрифт из массива байтов, а в релизе не могу.

Comment: @Абдулла что значит "не могу"? Что именно происходит? Падает ошибка? Какая именно?

Comment: Возникает ошибка сообщающая что метода `CreateFont` не смог создать шрифт из входного параметра `b`. В Debug все работает.

Comment: @Абдулла отредактируйте вопрос и приведите полный код для воспроизведения проблемы (который можно скопировать и запустить локально) + текст ошибки